# Change a float using a UI Button OnPointerDown

Tags: unity-game-engine, methods

I am fairly new to Unity and I am currently struggling to apply buttons to control the velocity of my character.

Here I have some code which adjusts my characters velocity depending on players input on Horizontal Axis.

```
 if (inGame)
    {
        //Movement
        if (isMoving)
        {
            movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;  
            Vector2 velocity = rb.velocity;
            velocity.x = movement;
            rb.velocity = velocity;}}
```

I am trying to change this to on screen buttons

---

```
public void SetDirectionLeft()
{
    movingLeft = true;
    Debug.Log("LEFT:" + movingLeft.ToString());
}
public void SetDirectionNull()
{
    movingLeft = false;
    movingRight = false;
    Debug.Log("STILL");
}
public void SetDirectionRight()
{
    movingRight = true;
    Debug.Log("RIGHT:" + movingRight.ToString());
}

public void SetMovingTrue()
{
    if (!isMoving)
    { isMoving = true; }

    Debug.Log("MOVING:" + isMoving.ToString());
}

public void SetMovingFalse()
{
    if (isMoving)
    { isMoving = false; }
    Debug.Log("MOVING:" + isMoving.ToString());
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (inGame)
    {
        //Movement
        if (isMoving)
        {
            if(movingLeft)
            {
                    movement = -movementSpeed;  //moves left on x axis -SPEED

            }
            else if (movingRight)
            {
                    movement = movementSpeed;   //moves right on x axis +SPEED
            }
            else
            {
                    movement = 0;               //NULL

            }
            Vector2 velocity = rb.velocity;
            velocity.x = movement;
            rb.velocity = velocity;
        }
    }
```

I have split the getters and setters up as you can see in the above image and when I click left button I set direction to -1.0f and if I click right I call the method to set direction to 1. I also Set Moving to true when either button is clicked.

OnPointerDown, isMoving sets TRUE
OnPointerUp, isMoving sets FALSE

this works now.
**EDIT** 
I have changed SetDirection to use bools and as shown in the following video isMoving successfully changes to true and false. movingLeft and movingRight do not change. However in the debug log you can see the values do change, but not for the player.

[GYAZOVIDEO.mp4](https://i.gyazo.com/9880a9eb83c3329c4b7839230e16a642.mp4)

**So my issue is why are my functions when called not changing the direction value?**

---

Here are the 35+ errors I get at the moment regarding a different issues.
My level generator spawn in power ups cloning the main power up, if two power ups collide on spawn I kill one. For some reason this results in these errors that do not affect my current issue. My original objects that are cloned have 2D Colliders so im not sure why the clones dont. Again new to Unity, GREAT PROGRAM.

---

My project is on simmer if you wish to try it
simmer.io/@ZakBrindle/burtle-jump

Comment: Unless you need to show some specific margin/error formatting in your IDE, could you replace those images with text? A code formatting tool is available.

Comment: Yes sorry will do now

Comment: You have 35 errors in your last image above and can you show them if one of them is your Player.cs script related?

Comment: Yes I have added this to the post and a comment regarding what is is

Comment: Okay, this errors which I see here is not your current problem related but I think it will disturb you in future, because it saying that there is missing collider component, which is very important when working on physics collissions

Comment: Yes its a strange one something i'm also looking into. The original object has a 2D sphere collider so im not sure why its throwing this issue but I will get to the bottom of it. So many swings and roundabouts :')

Comment: Can you try to remove "If(inGame)" and test if now works?

Comment: Or have you attached this monobehaviour component on proper GameObject?

Comment: Yes inGame == true always at the moment and only controls movement, but I think my issue lies with setting the direction value.     Also I think so, the script is attached to the player gameObject which is then dragged into the button BaseEventData

Comment: Apparently, you've only assigned SetDirectionLeft. Besides, is that event ever triggered? I can't find the Pointer Down documentation, because people are normally using ```OnClick``` for buttons. Could you please help with some details? Anyway, this ```if (direction != -1.0f)``` is redundant.

Comment: Yes the if( direction != -1) is redundant this was not here before and added when trying t solve this I will remove that again thank you. Where do I need PointerDown documentation? When pointer down isMoving is set to true and SetDirectionLeft is called. The method to set isMoving works but the method to SetDirection does nothing.

Comment: I copied  everything you asked and it's worked in my case, idk :D

Comment: Because its so right haha, thank you for confirming it works I will continue to break apart mine till I find the issue and will post here.

Thank you

Comment: Please write the answer if you fix the bug, I wonder what's the real problem here

Comment: Do you need to go by `bool`s? Wouldn't it be easier to simply say e.g. `void SetMovingLeft(){ rb.velocity = new Vector2(-movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y); }` and `SetMovingFalse(){ rb.velocity = Vector2.zero; }` etc

Comment: Using this when I press a button I get the following error.
https://i.gyazo.com/f725d244153700c05442d3d834cb6d4f.png

Comment: I also tried using SetMovingLeft with a bool as updated in OP but that isnt setting as shown in the video.

Comment: You are getting that error because you missed the GetComponent<Rigidbody>()

Comment: Of course, thanks. I have changed -movementSpeed to -10f and Debug.Log("rb.velocity.ToString") and the log shows rb.velocity is 0.0, 0.0 even when I hardcode -10. Its like the functions I am calling are not setting values. Am I referencing the method correctly in the onTriggerEvent

Comment: Fixed. Created a new script and added the code at the bottom of OP. Deleted and created new buttons added new triggers to the new script/player object. Thank you for the support

Answer (score 0):

To fix my issue I deleted the buttons and created new buttons from scratch and created a new PlayerMovement script with the following code. I attached this to the player and set the buttons up for the methods again. Not sure why I had to do this but it seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks

```
public void SetDirectionLeft()
{

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    Debug.Log("LEFT:" + rb.velocity.ToString());

}
public void SetDirectionNull()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    Debug.Log("STILL" + rb.velocity.ToString());
}
public void SetDirectionRight()
{

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    Debug.Log("RIGHT:" + rb.velocity.ToString());

}
```